# iOS storyboard scrollable design

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I need help to make the following design for one of the screens of my iOS app.

[image: iOS Storyboard Design]

I need the user to be able to scroll down and see more images of the product in the collection view at the bottom.

The green button at the end of the screen should be fixed and not scrolling.

The screen layout should be designed to look the same in all iPhone sizes.

I would really appreciate any storyboard file example.

Regards

Comment: use tableview, add your design as subview in tableview like we add headerview to tableview in storyboard for making your design scrollable in storyboard..

Comment: Thanks Dev, do you have any sample or tutorial giving steps of what you say? I still find it difficult to follow

Comment: What he meant is use an UIViewController, then add a collection view as a sub view.(not full height, buffer space for your button), then add the button at the button as another sub view of your UIViewController.view instead of a sub view of the collection view